# Problem installing player/gazebo

Tags: 10.04, installation

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 (64-bit). I have successfully installed all the dependencies of 
player and gazebo, then installed player 3.01 and then gazebo 0.9.

Now when I run this :

```
gazebo worlds/pioneer2dx.world
```

I get a gazebo interface.  Everything is OK up until this point, but when I run this command I see an error:

```
cd gazebo/player
player gazebo.cfg
player: error while loading shared libraries: libplayerdrivers.so.3.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I guess the problem is somewhere in the environmental variables --  can anyone please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should add the directory path containing your library into the LD_PATH variable of your environment.

Comment: hi greydet!! thnx for the reply, i found that libplayerdrivers.so.3.0 is present in /usr/local/lib64 , now i edited my bash.rc file like this,  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib64
and i get this errorusama@ubuntu:~/gazebo-0.9.0/player$ player gazebo.cfg 
Registering driver
Player v.3.0.1
error   : Failed to load plugin libgazeboplugin.
error   : libtool reports error: file not found
error   : plugin search path: /home/usama/gazebo-0.9.0/player:.:/usr/local/lib/
error   : failed to load plugin: libgazeboplugin
error   : failed to parse config file gazebo.cfg driver blocks

Comment: i am totally new to ubuntu , can u please write the commands which i have to write to edit my bash.rc

Comment: Once you have added the export command from your bashrc file, did you think to re-source it in your env or just close your current terminal window and reopening a new one for the bashrc to be reloaded?

Comment: i don't understand by re-source it in your env?  ,
i edited my bashrc file and then save it and then open a new terminal and try the commands , what else one has to do after editing the bashrc file ?

Comment: If you reopened a new terminal it is ok then, nothing much should be done. Are you sure your libplayerdrivers.so.3.0 file is directly located within /home/usama/gazebo-0.9.0/player directory?

Answer (score 1):

Using this [url](http://eecs.vanderbilt.edu/research/hmtl/wiki/pmwiki.php?n=Knowledge.PlayerStage), I have come up with these instructions:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/bash.bashrc
```

and then add the following to the `.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:"/usr/local/lib64"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:"/usr/local/lib":"/usr/local/lib64"
export PLAYERPATH="/usr/local/lib":"/usr/local/lib64"
export STAGEPATH="/usr/local/lib":"/usr/local/lib64"
```

Save it then run:

```
source /etc/bash.bashrc
```